# If the Fourier coefficients are all zero, does that imply the integeral over the absolute value of the intergrand also zero?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose $f : [-\pi, \pi] \to \mathbb C$ is a continuous function such that for all $m \in \mathbb Z $ the Fourier coefficient $\hat f(m) = 0.$
Let $p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_ke^{ikx}$ be a trig polynomial.

Which of the following is true?

1. $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)e^{ikx}|dx =0$.
2. $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)e^{ikx}|dx =0$.

One of the following questions is to show $f=0$ so I guess both are true, but I'm trying to show this is true in order to prove $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2dx=0$ by using the fact that for any Riemann integrable function there exists a sequence of trig polynomials $(p_n(x))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that

$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x) - p_n(x)|dx \xrightarrow {n \to \infty}  0$$

And so since $f$ is bounded (say by $M$) then we have:

$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2dx \leq M \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)-p_n(x)|dx + \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)p_n(x)|dx
$$

There exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $N \leq n$ we have:

$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2dx < \epsilon + \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)p_n(x)|dx
$$

Comment: @geetha290krm Perhaps I wasn't clear enough - I have yet to prove $f=0$, this is one step in its proof.

Comment: See Fourier Analysis by Edwards for a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any trigonometric polynomial $P$, we have
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)-P(x)|^2\,dx&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2\,dx-2\text{Re}\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\overline{P}(x)\,dx\right)+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|P(x)|^2\,dx\\
&= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2\,dx+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|P(x)|^2\,dx,
\end{align}
where the cross term vanishes since $\hat{f}=0$. Now, take a sequence of trigonometric polynomials $P_n$ which converge to $f$ in $L^2$ (actually, for continuous $f$, we can do better and approximate uniformly using Weierstrass’ approximation theorem). This implies
\begin{align}
0&=2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2\,dx,
\end{align}
and hence $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2\,dx=0$.

Note also that although you only asked about continuous $f$, it actually holds for any $f\in L^p$ with $1\leq p<\infty$, because we can first approximate $f\in L^p$ using a continuous $\phi$ (this is where we use $p\neq \infty$). By suitably cutting off the function $\phi$ near the endpoints we can ensure $\phi$ vanishes at (and in fact near) the endpoints while still being a good $L^p$ approximation to $f$ (the reason for cutting off, is so that we get something (which extends to be) periodic). Now, using the Stone-Weierstrass approximation theorem, we can uniformly (and hence in $L^p$) approximate $\phi$ by a sequence of trigonometric polynomials. Thus, every $f\in L^p([-\pi,\pi])$ can be approximated by trigonometric polynomials in the $L^p$ norm.

---

A-fortiori we can say both (i) and (ii) are true, but you shouldn’t put the absolute values in too early. For example, it might have been conceivable that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)P_n(x)|\,dx\neq 0$, even though $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)P_n(x)\,dx=0$ (of course, the argument above rules out this possibility from the assumption $\hat{f}=0$, but a-priori, we couldn’t have known this).

---

**Edit: Argument using only $L^1$ approximation**
Anyway, if you only know the $L^1$ approximation fact, then we have to argue slightly differently: for any continuous $f:[-\pi,\pi]\to\Bbb{C}$ and any trigonometric polynomial $P$, we have $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)P(x)\,dx=0$, so
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2\,dx&=\left|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2\,dx-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)P(x)\,dx\right|\\
&\leq\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|f(x)\overline{f}(x)-f(x)P(x)\right|\,dx\\
&\leq M\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|\overline{f}(x)-P(x)|\,dx,
\end{align}
where I denote $M=\sup\limits_{x\in [-\pi,\pi]}|f(x)|$. Now, take a sequence of trigonometric polynomials which approximate $\overline{f}$ in $L^1$. Then, the RHS vanishes. Hence, $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2\,dx=0$.

---

**Edit: Generalities**

Note that the versions above are not the most general. In the first, I assumed $f\in L^2$, while in the second, I assume $f$ is continuous (though that could have been weakened to $f\in L^{\infty}\cap L^1$). But in fact, the more general theorem is that if $f\in L^1$ is such that $\hat{f}=0$, then $f=0$ a.e.

To argue in this case, note that by hypothesis, $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)P(x)\,dx=0$ for all trigonometric polynomials $P$. By the Stone-Weierstrass approximation theorem, for any continuous function $g:[-\pi,\pi]\to\Bbb{C}$ with $g(-\pi)=g(\pi)$, we can find a sequence of trigonometric polynomials $P_n$ which uniformly approximate $g$. So,
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)g(x)\,dx\right|&=\left|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)g(x)\,dx-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)P_n(x)\,dx\right|\\
&\leq\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|\,dx\cdot \sup_{x\in [-\pi,\pi]}|g(x)-P_n(x)|,
\end{align}
and the RHS vanishes as $n\to\infty$. Hence, $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)g(x)\,dx=0$. By a suitable variant of the classical “fundamental lemma of calculus of variations”, it follows that $f=0$ a.e.

Comment: See, my problem here is that so far in class we've only shown there exists a sequence of trig polynomials that converge to $f$ in $L^1$, not in $L^2$. Also, could you explain why this implies $2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2dx = 0$? And one last thing, by Weierstrass' theorem we can approximate $f$ uniformly with a sequence of continuous function that aren't necessarily trig polynomials, right?

Comment: @YYY1998 sorry, I meant Stone-Weierstrass, (Weierstrass’ approximation gives us an approximation using polynomials, not trigonometric polynomials) but here also one has to be slightly careful. I’ll edit shortly (but what I said is true: every $f\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ can be approximated in $L^2$ using trig polynomials).

Comment: next, I’m using that in general if $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$, then $\|f_n\|_{L^p}\to \|f\|_{L^p}$ simply by the (reverse) triangle inequality: $|\|f_n\|_{L^p}-\|f\|_{L^p}|\leq \|f_n-f\|_{L^p}$, and the RHS approaches $0$. Now, raising to the $p^{th}$ power (if $1\leq p<\infty$) tells us $\int_X|f_n|^p\,d\mu\to\int_X|f|^p\,d\mu$.

Comment: @YYY1998 I have edited to give an argument using only the $L^1$ approximation.