# Uniqueness of Fourier expansion in $L^1(\mathbb{T})$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I want to prove the theorem:

> If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ and $\hat{f}(n) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$,then f(x) = 0 for almost everywhere.

This is my current proof,I can only prove that if $f \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ and bounded case,and I would like everyone to help me check if there are any issues with my proof.

My proof:

Since,

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)e^{-inx} dx = 0 ,n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

So for any trigonometric polynomial p(x),there is :

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)p(x) dx = 0$$

and since the trigonometric polynomials are dense in $L^1(\mathbb{T})$,then for any given $\varepsilon >0$,there is a trigonometric polynomial $p_{\varepsilon}(x)$ satisfies $||f-p_{\varepsilon}||_{1} < \varepsilon$,since the function is bounded then :

$$\begin{aligned} \left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) (f(x) - p_{\varepsilon}(x))\right| dx  &\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(x) (f(x) - p_{\varepsilon}(x))| dx \\&< M \varepsilon \end{aligned}$$

Therefore,$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^2(x) dx =0 \implies f(x) =0 $ a.e.

- Is my proof correct under the stronger condition?
- How should the original theorem be proven?

Comment: For all trigonometric polynomials, $\int_If(x)p(x)\,dx=0$, where $I=[-\pi,\pi]$. By Stone-Weierstrass, continuous periodic functions on a compact interval can be uniformly approximated by trigonometric polynomials, so $\int_I f(x)g(x)\,dx=0$ for continuous periodic $g$. This is more than enough, by fundamental lemma of calculus of variations to conclude $f=0$ a.e (you only need all $g\in C^{\infty}_c((-\pi,\pi))$). There are several proofs of this, for example you can go through Lebesgue’s differentiation theorem, or you can use Lusin’s theorem to upgrade to all $g\in L^{\infty}$ etc etc.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4711855/568204) for some of these remarks slightly more fleshed out.

Comment: Your proof is good.

Comment: Or keep your proof, but instead of approximating $f$ with trigonometric polynomials, just approximate sign$(f)$.

Answer (score 2):

Pick some $X \in (-\pi,\pi)$, and let $s_n$ be the continuous function whose graph connects the points $(-\pi,0), (x-{1 \over n}, 0), (x,1), (\pi-{1 \over n}, 1), (\pi, 0)$. Let $p_n$ be a trigonometric polynomial such that $\|s_n-p_n\|_\infty < {1 \over n}$, and let $s=1_{[x,\pi)}$. An application of the dominated convergence theorem gives $\int f s = \int_{-\pi}^x f = 0$. Since this holds for all $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$, the differentiation theorem shows that $f=0$ ae.